# click button once in a div instead of all divs

Tags: vb.net

Basically i'd like to click this "button" only once in the div "test1-header" (this button is present in every div, and has no name or id, but i can click it by his class)

```
<div class="test1-header">
 <td class="button">  '' only this button i want to click
<div class="test2-header">
 <td class="button">
<div class="test3-header">
 <td class="button">
```

But when i execute my code it clicks all the buttons inside all 3 divs on the page.

Basically this is my action code:

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
        For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
            If webpageelement.GetAttribute("className") = "button" Then
                webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

I hope i can separate these divs or something. Some help please :D

// edit - This the code i've modified based on what Crowcoder said but it doesn't work :(

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("data-aid") = "115553109754009608849"   Then
            For Each elem As HtmlElement In webpageelement.Children
                If elem.GetAttribute("className") = "mod-button" Then
                    elem.InvokeMember("click")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

// edit - Okay, so this is the HTML i'm dealing with, with all the parent divs of the button

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id=""body-container"">
   <div id=""page-container"">
    <div id=""content"">
     <div class=""branded-page-v2-container branded-page-base-bold-titles branded-page-v2-container-flex-width branded-page-v2-secondary-column-hidden"">
      <div class=""branded-page-v2-col-container"">
       <div class=""branded-page-v2-col-container-inner"">
        <div class=""branded-page-v2-primary-col"">
         <div class=""   yt-card  clearfix"">
          <div class=""branded-page-v2-primary-col-header-container branded-page-v2-primary-column-content"">
           <div class=""branded-page-v2-body branded-page-v2-primary-column-content"">
            <div id=""watch-response"">
             <div id=""watch-response-content"">
              <div id=""watch-discussion"">
               <div id=""comments embedded"">
                <div class=""comments-list"">
                 <div class=""comment-entry"">
                  <div data-aid=""101515802118596397194"">   ''<-- this is a unique value of it's closest parent div
                   <div class=""content"">
                    <div class=""comment-footer"">
                     <div class=""comment-footer-actions"">
                      <table class=""footer-button-bar"">
                       <tbody>
                        <tr>
                         <td class=""mod-button"">  ''<-- this is the button i'd like to push
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                       </tbody>
                      </table>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. Your divs are not closed and you cannot have td as a direct child of div. I don't know how that markup will behave, but normally what you would do is find the closest parent to the element you want if the element you want is not unique in some way. Then you inspect the children, hopefully there is something unique about the element you want within the context of its parent.
Here is an example demonstrating this technique with better HTML:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><div class=""test1-header""><div class=""button"" onclick=""alert('foo')""></div> test </div></body></html>"

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("className") = "test1-header" Then
            For Each elem As HtmlElement In webpageelement.Children
                If elem.GetAttribute("className") = "button" Then
                    elem.InvokeMember("click")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the in-depth explanation that you offered (i'm a noob and it helps me see the bigger picture). So far i've modified my code, but i can't seem to get it right so far, although i'm 25% closer now with your help :D

Comment: I've edited my HTML code so if you could look into it it would mean the world to me! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have control over this document such that you can just give it a unique id? Otherwise you would need to make something like what I have shown into a recursive function to walk the entire DOM.

Comment: No, i don't have any control over it whatsoever. i don't really understand how and where to implement that recursive function to walk the DOM. I'm definitely looking into it for the rest of the day because it looks like a good bone to chew on, but If you could give me a starting point or a reference on how to do it, that would be something! :P

Comment: here is an example of recursively walking the entire DOM. You can adapt it to inspect attribute values for what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.children(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: I've done it this morning! Based on what you replied i got a friend to help me complete the code, and now it's working 100% with 0 problems :D kudos to you